# For Each Compile Error (Multiple ranges)

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

All,

I'm sure there is a quick answer however this has frustrated me for a good hour so apologies if the question is very basic.

I have a For Each loop which I need to iterate through several times, however when I type in greater than two ranges to iterate through the screenshot error is displayed.

```
    Dim TargetCell As Range, ICol As Integer
    Set TargetCell = Rows("9").Find(What:="Forecast", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not TargetCell Is Nothing Then ICol = TargetCell.Column



For Each c In Range(Cells(12, ICol), Cells(18, 73), Cells(19, ICol), Cells(42, 73), Cells(47, ICol), Cells(53, 73), Cells(55, ICol), Cells(76, 73))
```

any help with the error would be greatly appreciated

Compile Error message:
[image]

*****UPDATE

I have updated my code to have unions, This has resolved the issue with the forums help
Please see new code below;

```
Dim Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, Rng4 As Range

Set Rng1 = Range(Cells(12, ICol), Cells(18, 73))
Set Rng2 = Range(Cells(19, ICol), Cells(42, 73))
Set Rng3 = Range(Cells(47, ICol), Cells(53, 73))
Set Rng4 = Range(Cells(55, ICol), Cells(76, 73))

 Dim C as variant
    For Each c In Union(Rng1, Rng2, Rng3, Rng4)
```

Posting answer for future reference

Comment: You need to use `Range.Union`

Comment: Thanks! @cyboashu How would I apply this to the For loop?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50160025/edit) to include more information if necessary.

Comment: `Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range` -> Declare it this way. Otherwise `Rng4` is range, and the rest is a `Variant`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, works perfectly and learnt something new :)

Comment: Always declare `Option Explicit` at the top and declare your varaibles one per line. It makes things easier for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to make a loop of cells. As mentioned in the comments, `Range.Union` is really a good idea. Another one is to put all the cells in one array and to loop through them like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim c As Variant
    Dim Icol As Long:    Icol = 5

    For Each c In Array(Cells(12, Icol), Cells(18, 73), Cells(19, Icol), Cells(42, 73))
        Debug.Print c.Address
        c.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SB999 - it is really tough to guess what you mean, without seeing any relevant code. Still, I guess that you are passing the `rng1`, `rng2`, `rng3` from your question to an array? If this is the fact, then you need another `for each loop`, for every cell of `rng1` and etc. Still, it is a good idea to ask separatly with the relevant code.